# Verification task in gradle

Tags: java, groovy, gradle

While I was reading the [gradle documentation 23.3](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/java_plugin.html) I faced with the verification task concept in the following context:

> Performs all verification tasks in the project.

Couldn't you explain what it means?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `check` task doesn't do anything by itself. All it does by default is depending on the `test` task, which executes unit tests.

But if you apply other plugins like `pmd`, `checkstyle` or `findbugs`, for example, those plugins will add other verification tasks to the `check` task dependencies, so that, when you execute the `check` task, the unit tests will be run, but static PMD, checkstyle and findbugs analysis of the source/byte code will be executed as well.

And of course, if you decide to add, for example, a custom `integrationTest` task, you can also add this task to the dependencies of `check` so that `check` also executes the integration tests.

Comment: This information should be added to the official documentation of the Java plugin too.